# Can I create a temporary sudo shell?

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I love the feature of sudo where after authenticating once, for the next N minutes (15?) when I run `sudo` I don't have to input my password.

I often do work inside a tmux window and I've developed a bad habit of doing `sudo -s` and then getting distracted and leaving my root shell active for quite a while.

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds? I don't want to have to type `sudo` before every command, but I also don't want to leave my shell logged in as root. I think it would be great to be able to do `sudo -s` and then if I don't run any commands for several minutes it would drop me back to a regular shell.

Is there a way to do this without a bunch of hacky workarounds? And if not, are there a bunch of hacky workarounds that I can use?

Comment: It should be pretty obvious you are using a root terminal, because the `$` gets turned into a `#`. Have you tried `sudo -i` to lose your user environment, to remind you that your main profile is not root?

Comment: @oldmud0 its not that I forget that I'm in a root shell - it's that it's logged in, which is a security risk

Comment: ~~Actually, both would log you into `root` - however, `sudo -s` keeps your user environment (which is a greater security risk; [see the bottom of this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35344)) whereas `sudo -i` ensures that it is fresh and remains isolated from your user environment.~~ Oops, I get what you're saying now. The best solution is to not log in as root, and perform individual commands with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a way to make a terminal log, which I suspect is possible, you do a script that opens a logging terminal as root in one process and opens another process to run a script that monitors the log and kills the terminal and deletes the log when the log doesn't change for 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If I get right what are you looking for then you can use `vlock` in `tmux` sessions

```
echo '
set-option -g lock-command vlock
set-option -g lock-after-time 900
' >> ~./.tmux.conf
```